# Form padding differences in Firefox and Opera/Chrome/IE

Tags: css, firefox, padding

I'm having a problem with the padding in my form on my website.
If I've set a height/width to a form element and then adds a padding to it. In all browsers I've tried, except Firefox, the padding is added to the height/width.

If I have a input with 200 in width and 20px in height. and padding at 5 (all ways), the sum and total width and height would be 210px and 30px, but in Firefox it is 200px and 20px.

How do I work my way around this?

Comment: Link to page?  Did you set a DOCTYPE?

Comment: It's not online yet. ;\
I've read about someone having issue with this earlier, but I haven't found any answers.

I have set doctype to xhtml trans.

Comment: The document is also valid in xhtml strict

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Give the `input` this CSS:

```css
box-sizing: border-box;
```

You can read more about `box-sizing` on [QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html), [the W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing), and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing). Here is [its browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing). Use the prefixes `-moz-` or `-webkit-` if required by your target browsers.

---

This answer had previously suggested the value `initial`, which I had found by using the up/down arrow keys in the Chrome Web Inspector. But it turns out that [`initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) is a CSS keyword, applicable to any property, that represents the initial value of the property – the browser’s default value. `initial` is less safe than explicitly naming which box model to use. If `box-sizing: initial` were specified and a browser’s default value for `box-sizing` changed, the `input`’s padding could break again.

Comment: thanks! that was exactly what I was looking for, `box-sizing: border-box;` did the trick :) sorry for the late reply!

Comment: or. when I see my question again it looks like I've been used to the padding problem. I guess `box-sizing: content-box;` is the right option to get the total width/height of 210px/30px. I think the traditional box model is more logical (cf [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html) )..

Comment: FYI, adding `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` to your CSS file sets all elements to border-box, which will maintain an element's width and height even when adding margin and padding. The default box modal `content-box` adds padding and margins onto your element's width, which in many people's opinion is illogical and difficult to work with. Read more here http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/. EDIT: Forgot to add, `border-box` is supported in IE8 and up, so it's safe to use.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use a CSS framework such as [blueprint-css](http://blueprintcss.org). Take a look the example pages that ship with blueprint (there's a file called `forms.html`). This should solve your padding problem as well as a bunch of other problems you may encounter.

Comment: I saw the blueprint form css-file and it seems like `input[type=text]` did the trick on the input field at least..!

Now I only need to solve it on the textarea, I'll look into it!
Thanks (:

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting display:block on the form? It sounds like FF might possibly be treating it like it was an inline element.

Comment: `display: inline-block` might be better

Answer (score 0):

http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/

```
/*
 * 1. Addresses box sizing set to content-box in IE 8/9.
 * 2. Removes excess padding in IE 8/9.
 * 3. Removes excess padding in IE 7.
 *    Known issue: excess padding remains in IE 6.
 */

input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
    box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */
    padding: 0; /* 2 */
    *height: 13px; /* 3 */
    *width: 13px; /* 3 */
}

/*
 * 1. Addresses `appearance` set to `searchfield` in Safari 5 and Chrome.
 * 2. Addresses `box-sizing` set to `border-box` in Safari 5 and Chrome
 *    (include `-moz` to future-proof).
 */

input[type="search"] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield; /* 1 */
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box; /* 2 */
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
/* Set all margins and paddings to 0 on all browsers */

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect, the browser's default styles should not have anything to do with the phenomenon the question is asking about