# Input Padding Cross-Browser Issue?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, cross-browser

I have a search form that should look like this:

[image]

This is the HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="#" class="search-form">
    <input type="text" class="nav-search-input input-initial" data-initial='Search' value="Search">
    <input type="submit" class="nav-search-submit" value="&#57384;"><!-- &#57384; is the code for the Glyphicons search icon -->
</form>
```

I'm using Bootstrap and Bootstrap Responsive styles, as well as the following styles for the search form:

```
.search-form{
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
}

input.nav-search-input,
input.nav-search-submit{
    color: #eeeeee;
    background-color: #181818;

    border-top: 1px solid #303030;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #303030;
}

input.nav-search-input{
    width: 90px;
    height: 20px;

    -moz-transition:border-color 75ms;
    -o-transition:border-color 75ms;
    -webkit-transition:border-color 75ms;

    outline: 0!important;
    -webkit-appearance:none!important;
    box-shadow: none!important;
    -moz-box-shadow: none!important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none!important;
    margin-top: 10px;

    padding: 0px 0px 0px 8px;

    line-height: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;

    border-right: none;
    border-left: 1px solid #303030;

    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;


    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;

    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;

}

input.nav-search-submit{
    font-family: Glyphicons;

    box-sizing: content-box;

    padding: 0px 6px 0px 5px;

    color: #aaaaaa;

    -moz-transition:border-color 75ms;
    -o-transition:border-color 75ms;
    -webkit-transition:border-color 75ms;

    border-left: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #303030;

    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;

    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

This works great on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, but Opera is rendering the form like this:

[image]

The version of Opera in question is 12.02.

It appears to be an issue with the padding. I've tried the solutions listed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354470/form-padding-differences-in-firefox-and-opera-chrome-ie) to no avail. If I increase the top and bottom padding to make it look correct in Opera, it no longer looks correct in the other browsers.

Here is a [working version of the page](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/23262910/test/test.html).

Side note, I haven't tested in IE as I'm on a Mac.

Comment: I wanted to test some line-height fixes, but pointed my Opera 22 to your dropbox sample page and is not available anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of thoughts:

1. You're relying on a font to produce that magnifying glass... That's
   risky. Some devices don't support @face fonts (replace Glyphicons
   with Droid Sans, and you'll see what some of your users are going to
   get - padding won't matter)
2. Have you simply tried using `<input type="image"...>`
3. Have you tried using `{ background:url('mag-glass') }`

I've got $50 that says your problem has to do with how opera is rendering that font, or the line-height of that font. And yes -- fixing that for Opera will jack FF, Chrome, and Safari up.

Also, I buzzed through your CSS files, and didn't see a CSS reset. See Eric Meyer's CSS reset for more info. Takes a lot of the little headaches away when everything has been 'equalized' in a reset.

Comment: Thanks, it _did_ end up being an issue with how different browsers rendered the font. I ended up using a `background-image`.

Answer (score 0):

inputs always cause issues with cross-browser css.

I advise You to use good css reset and input containers, like

```
<div class="input-border">
    <input type="text" name="cokolwiek">
</div>
```

It breaks couple rules - "do not mix html and style", but it works ;]

Remember about :focus outline.