# Input Field appearing different in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css

I've tested in Chrome, it shows fine but when in Firefox, the input box is larger than expected.

Here is the markup:

```
<div class="form-wrapper">           
    <input type="search" name="Ofsearch"
            placeholder="Search here..." value=""/> 
    <button id="searchButton" type="submit">
        Search
    </button>
</div>
```

Here is the style:

```
.form-wrapper {
     height: 80px;
     clear: both;
}

.form-wrapper input {
     border-radius: 10px;
     border: 5px solid #E5E4E2;
     margin: 2px;
     height: 40px;
     vertical-align: middle;
     padding: 20px;
     margin-top: 15px;
     width: 85%;
}

.form-wrapper button {
     overflow: visible;
     position: absolute;
     float: right;
     border: 0;
     padding: 0;
     height: 40px;
     width: 110px;
     border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
     margin: 20px -118px;
}
```

Here is the example in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J8dSN/1/).

As you can see from the example, when in Chrome and Firefox, they show in different sizes.

When I check this issue, I found the `padding:20px` in `.form-wrapper input{ }` has caused this problem. However, when I delete it, Firefox shows fine, but the input area gets smaller in Chrome. Just wondering, any way to make it displayed the same in both browsers.

Comment: For anyone having a similar problem for another reason, solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43361500/2873507

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a difference because Firefox uses `box-sizing: content-box` on `type="search"` inputs, while Chrome uses `border-box`.

```
.form-wrapper input {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J8dSN/12/

Comment: Hi, this fixed the problem, however, it seems that the inputs are still at it's original position,can't see what we type into now. How to change it? see http://jsfiddle.net/J8dSN/13/

Comment: You can reduce the padding on `.form-wrapper input` to 10px and increase it's height to 50px. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/J8dSN/15/

Answer (score 0):

I think this will probably answer your question: [Form padding differences in Firefox and Opera/Chrome/IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354470/form-padding-differences-in-firefox-and-opera-chrome-ie)

Different browsers handle attributes like padding and borders from different starting points