# How to center inputs and button in webkit browsers without shift?

Tags: html, css

```
<style>
html {
    text-align: center;
}

input, button {
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
</style>
<html>
<form>
    <input value="test" type="text">
    <br>
    <button>Test</button>
</form>
</html>
```

Hey, when I try this Code in Microsoft Edge, it works fine, but when i try it in Webkit-browser (e.g. Opera) there is a shift of the button.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5LNi.png)

Comment: I created a codepen for you: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zoergP  tested this on Chrome 55, the small space on the left is there, so it is a webkit issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue related to: [Input Field Chrome and Firefox shows different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18582606/input-field-chrome-and-firefox-shows-different). So your question might be a duplicate.

> There is a difference because Firefox uses box-sizing: content-box on type="search" inputs, while Chrome uses border-box.

Your issue can be fixed by applying border-box to both elements:

```
input, button {
width: 300px;
height: 50px;
margin-top: 10px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

You can see the result here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QGYNWN

If you check your code you'll notice that the input is 303px instead of 300. And the button is 300px, as it should be. The border-box property makes them both 300px. You can confirm with the console.

Comment: when i try the codepen.io link in opera, there is still shift of the button.

Comment: Did you check through the console to see if both elements have the same width?

Comment: yes, they both have the same width, but there is still a shift http://imgur.com/a/s4GaH