# Bootstrap modal looks differently in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

The height of the same bootstrap modal inner elements is different in two browsers.

In Chrome the height of `.modal-dialog` and `.modal-content` is bigger.

Here is the jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/qLcopxsb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it's the same, [see this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qLcopxsb/2/)

I've changed this :

```
form {
    margin: 40px 40px 0;
}
```

However I can't explain why, I don't know why. Maybe check this link for further information about this phenomenon : 
[Form padding differences in Firefox and Opera/Chrome/IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354470/form-padding-differences-in-firefox-and-opera-chrome-ie)

Comment: Thank you so much!